# How to store a reference to a procedure in a Fortran derived type

Tags: fortran

Can I store a reference to a procedure  inside a Fortran type?

My goal is to reduce repeated arguments into a Fortran subroutine by grouping them into a type. However Fortran doesn't let me do this for external procedures.

Here is a simplified example of what I try to do:

```
module my_functions
    type mytype
        external :: f
    end type
contains
    subroutine fa()
        WRITE(*,*) "yiha"
    end subroutine

    subroutine fb(t)
        type(mytype) t
        call t%f()
    end subroutine
end module

program test
    use my_functions
    type(mytype) :: m
    m%f = fa
    call fb(m)
end program
```

However gfortran gives me

```
     external :: f
                 1
Error: Unexpected attribute declaration statement at (1)
```

Comment: Concretely, I have an object that depends on several user provided external functions, and I don't want to pass all of them every time I call a method on that object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A derived type may have procedure pointers as components:

```
implicit none

type mytype
  procedure(), pointer, nopass :: f
end type

type(mytype) m

external fa
m%f => fa

call m%f()

end
```

This type has a procedure with an implicit interface which is referenced later as a subroutine.  Because it has an implicit interface, the `nopass` attribute is required for the pointer.